# Move Directory to Google Bucket

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage

How can we move entire folder(within folder have many sub directory too) to Bucket of google cloud? Can anyone help on this.

Comment: please _edit_ your question to show us what you have tried so far and where you struggle, including any error messages you get. then we can help with solving those errors.

Comment: do you want to create a C# function to do this? or only, do you want to know the alternatives to upload a folder?

Comment: ya. i want to create C#  function for that @JAHDZP

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I have go through the google cloud documentation . they provide only file(object) upload details. i just want to upload all the object(folder and subfolder files) to cloud

Answer (score 1):

Use `-r` flag in `gsutil` copy command.

From [gsutil documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp):

If you want to copy an entire directory tree you need to use the -r option. For example, to upload the directory tree "dir":

```
gsutil cp -r mydir gs://my-bucket
```

Comment: i want to create C# function for that

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud Storage Client for C # library does not support uploading folders, you must create a function (sync / asynchronous) that gets all the files/subfolders inside your folder and uploads each file.

I found a folder iterator code in this Microsoft [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-iterate-through-a-directory-tree) In my code example I added the GCS library to [upload the files](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#c), it is not necessary to create a folder structure.

For example

```
// GCS dependencies
using Google.Apis.Storage.v1;
using Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data;
using Google.Cloud.Storage.V1;
using Storage;
// GCS dependencies

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Cryptography;



static void WalkDirectoryTree(System.IO.DirectoryInfo root)
   {
       System.IO.FileInfo[] files = null;
       System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;

       // initialize the GCS client library
       var storage = StorageClient.Create();
       // use this variable to define the upload bucket, please use your bucket name
       var bucketName= Myawesomebucket
       try
       {
           files = root.GetFiles("*.*");
       }

       catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
       {

       }

       catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
       }

       if (files != null)
       {
           foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in files)
           {
               // If we
               // want to open, delete or modify the file, then
               // a try-catch block is required here to handle the case
               // where the file has been deleted since the call to TraverseTree().
               Console.WriteLine(fi.FullName);

               // this section is used to upload files to GCS
               // the object name includ folder/subfolder structure
               objectName = objectName ?? Path.GetFileName(fi.FullPath);

               // upload the object to the bucket
               storage.UploadObject(bucketName, objectName, null, f);
               Console.WriteLine($"Uploaded {objectName}.");

           }

           // Now find all the subdirectories under this directory.
           subDirs = root.GetDirectories();

           foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirs)
           {
               // Resursive call for each subdirectory.
               WalkDirectoryTree(dirInfo);
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: ya. i too searched many  reference. there is no option for that. we can only iterate and then need to move. Thanks @jahdzp